# change input value by component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

guys I have an input that when changing the value it executes a function in the component

```
    <input class="form-control" (change)="updateQuantidade($event.target.value, item)" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="{{item.estoque.estAtual}}" value="{{item.quantidade}}">



updateQuantidade(value: string, item: IItem) {
this.quantidade = Number(value);
if (Number(value) > item.estoque.estAtual) {
  this.quantidade = this.item.estoque.estAtual;
  item.quantidade = this.quantidade
  this.modalS.createModal(MdAlertComponent, { title: 'Estoque insuficiente', message: `Só há ${item.estoque.estAtual} unidade(s) deste item em estoque` });
}
```

}

if `item.quantidade` is greater than `item.estoque.estAtual`

it changes the value of `this.quantidade` for the same value of  `this.item.estoque.estAtual`

in the component it changes the value, but in the input it remains the old value, can someone help me with this?

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<dt *ngIf="this.quantidade > item.estoque.estAtual" 
style="padding-right: 10px;">Em estoque: 
{{item.estoque.estAtual}} </dt>
<h5>{{this.quantidade}}</h5>this.quantidade
<h5>{{item.estoque.estAtual}}</h5>item.estoque.estAtual

<dl class="dlist-inline">
<dt style="padding-right: 10px;">Quantidade: </dt>
<dd>
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="this.quantidade" 
(ngModelChange)="updateQuantidade(item)" type="number" 
name="quantity" min="1" max="{{item.estoque.estAtual}}" >

<!--<input class="form-control" 
(change)="updateQuantidade($event.target.value, item)" 
type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max=" 
{{item.estoque.estAtual}}" value="{{item.quantidade}}">
--></dd>
  </dl>
<div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The new html code

```
<input
class="form-control"
[(ngModel)]="quantidade"
                          
(ngModelChange)="updateQuantidade(item)"
type="number"
name="quantity"
min="1"
/>
```

if you just put a value like 5 for example, it replaces it with 3, but if you put a 4 right after 3, getting a total of 34 it doesn't do the replacement
i made one stackblitz for help
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1gv68s?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[(ngModel)]="this.quantidade"`instead of using the $event.target.value, and use (ngModelChange) to call a function on change. Note: you don't need to use `value="{{item.quantidade}}"` anymore since `[(ngModel)]` will automatically bind the input to `this.quantidade`.

In your .html file:

```html
<input 
   class="form-control" 
   [(ngModel)]="quantidade"
   (ngModelChange)="updateQuantidade(item)" 
   type="number" 
   name="quantity" 
   min="1" 
/>
```

In your component.ts file:

```js
updateQuantidade( item: IItem) {
  if (this.quantidade > item.estoque.estAtual) {
    this.quantidade = this.item.estoque.estAtual;
    item.quantidade = this.quantidade
    this.modalS.createModal(MdAlertComponent, { title: 'Estoque insuficiente', 
    message: `Só há ${item.estoque.estAtual} unidade(s) deste item em estoque` 
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: the code worked, but when testing I put the this.quantidade = 55 and the item.estoque.estAtual = 3 
it updates on this.quantidade  but they don't update in the input, that's strange

Comment: if I put values ​​like 11,23,25 it updates in the input too, but values ​​like 44,55,60,61 it doesn't update in the input

Comment: values ​​like 4,5,6,7 it only updates on the this.quantidade but it doesn't update in the component

Comment: I will show a print to make it clearer, at the top of the question

Comment: the limit is 3, values ​​that start with the first value below 3, for example 11,21,25 it is changed in the input, but values ​​that start with 3 or are greater than 3 it changes in the item.quantidade, but does not change in the input

Comment: You need to remove `this.` in `[(ngModel)]="this.quantidade"` : so it gives `[(ngModel)]="quantidade"`, I updated my answer to fix the problem, my bad.

Comment: Okay, tell me if that worked!

Comment: but the value is still in the input, just like the print I put in the question

Comment: if item.estoque.estAtual  for 3, values ​​like that start with 1 or 2 it changes in the input too, but values ​​that start from 3 it doesn't change in the input and continue as I typed it, for example 33.56

Comment: So, you didn't try with the exact code I gave you? Did you remove `this.`from `[(ngModel)]="this.quantidade"` ?

Comment: yes i tried, I will update the question

[(ngModel)]="quantidade"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246554/discussion-between-theophile-wallez-and-suporte-esallabs).